# Admob Banner position wrong(Unity3d)

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

When I click on the text box.
bottom position changing.

Tested device:
Samsung note 10.1
Android 4.1.2
Unity 5.6.5p4

Please look up to video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z9r64f5_66s

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From [AdMob documentation:](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/banner)

> For greater control over where a BannerView is
>   placed on screen than what's offered by AdPosition values, use the
>   BannerViewconstructor that has x- and y-coordinates as parameters:

```
// Create a 320x50 banner ad at coordinate (0,50) on screen.
BannerView bannerView = new BannerView(adUnitId, AdSize.Banner, 0, 50);
The top-left corner of the BannerView will be positioned at the x and y values passed to the constructor, where the origin is the top-left of the screen.
```

Comment: Try to reset the banner after the event and it should come back to the start/desired position.